# Why does Hinduism advocate Kanya-Dan over Putra-Dan?

Tags: marriage, tradition, women, customs

Why do Hindu women leave their parents' house and go to husbands or in-laws place after marriage?

While this is a custom among almost all the religions; I'm interested in knowing if there is any reference to this in Hindu scriptures.

What do scriptures say as to why it is this way or how it benefits society or the married couple?

To put it in simple words, Why is there concept of **Kanya-Dana** and not **Putra-Dana** in Hinduism?

Comment: I don't understand your [comment](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17651/why-do-women-leave-their-fathers-house-after-marriage#comment46076_17661) under Rickross's deleted answer. Maybe you should add those details to your question. You could add: 'Why isn't Kanyaa-daana other way round?' Also, not sure what you mean by 'how could it benefit the child?' BTW, in South India there is a concept of husband staying at wife's place after marriage especially if wife and her parents are wealthy. Win-win situation for both :P

Comment: @sv. Thanx ! Edited. Ignore that benefitting Child part for now. That win-win situation exists here too ;) :D LOL

Comment: gotra is passed on through male, not female. after marriage, the woman is now considered to be whatever gotra her husband is, and she is called kula-vadhu (lineage-wife). Later, their son would performs rites (tarpanam, shraddham, any sankalpams) based on that gotra only, not the woman's birth-gotra. Same gotra marriage is not allowed (similar to sibling marraige). For these reasons, women go their husband's house since she becomes part of his lineage.

Comment: You think other religions have putradaan? For e.g., in Xianity, the father "gives away the bride". It seems to have become a fashion to condemn every practice as one enforced by Hinduism even if it is not a bad practice.

Comment: @moonstar2001 wel i dont think my question is condemning anything. I'm honestly seeking answer to a genuine query i have. And i believe we all are here for that. Not to keep u in suspense, i dont think concept of putradan exists in any religion.